# Use Oracle 6 from ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracleclient

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 web application. It uses "System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0" to access an oracle database.
I get the following exception on connection:
*System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.*
I looked it up and found several articles/posts that say that the error is misleading and it is caused by some security issues of ASP.NET user trying to access oracle HOME folder.
However in my case my client's oracle client is indeed older that 8.1.7. In fact it is version 6! I know this is very old but you understand that this cannot change.
What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be confusing the Oracle Forms version numbering with the Oracle Database Server numbering. Oracle server version 6 was released back in '88 and I doubt that it would run under any current OS. Oracle Forms 6.0 was more recent (maybe ten years old) and runs quite happily on Windows XP as I recall.

That said, Forms 6.0 would have used the SQL*net 8.0 client which would still give the problem. If you type tnsping on the command line, that might give you a version number.

You can download a (free) InstantClient from the oracle web site. This can be unzipped on the same machine as another Oracle client. You may have to play a bit with path settings to make sure that the correct client is picked up by the .Net

Answer (score 1):

Find another job?  Seriously, version 6?!

I think you'd be better off recommending converting to MySQL (it's free). This is just one example of why your software should at least be from the current decade. You're just not going to find software that supports stuff that old. Your client is going to find it harder and harder to get people who know anything about it (or want to), and they'll pay more and more for it. How much are they going to spend trying to solve this problem? What about the next one? I think you owe it to your client to make a very strong case to upgrade somehow.

Good luck...

Comment: I think that oracle install is now of legal drinking age in the U.S.!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install a more recent version of Oracle which is supported by .Net, and CREATE a [DATABASE LINK](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm) to your current installation.

Comment: If you can legally do that it implies you have Oracle support. If you do, why not upgrade?